# Everything invisible in viewport

Tags: 3d-view, error, drivers

Regardless of what viewport mode I'm in, everything is completely invisible. For the record I am using Blender 2.80 and this started after a graphics driver update. I've tried reinstalling blender 2.8 and it didn't help. However, 2.9 does not have this problem. But, there is an addon that has not been updated to 2.9 that I am in need of for my current project.

Edit: 2.9 no longer works either
[image]